# Medal of Honor for retreating before an enemy?

Tags: united-states, military

The Highest award for valor in the United States Armed Services is the [Medal of Honor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medal_of_Honor); sometimes referred to the [Congressional Medal of Honor](http://www.cmohs.org).

Has anyone received this high honor while retreating in the face of the enemy?

Comment: The Congressional Medal of Honor society website maintains a [list of all recipients](http://www.cmohs.org/recipient-archive.php), together with the citation for each. It should be possible to go through and see which, if any, were awarded for actions during a retreat.

Comment: Not my dog-fight - I'm British - but - 1 for lack of clarity in the question. Conspicuous gallantry is possible *during* a retreat - rearguard action, retrieving fallen comrades, etc. *Headlong flight* before the enemy would hardly count as conspicuous gallantry in any Army.

Comment: I don't think there is anything negative associated with the retreat.   MacAurthur was following orders.   But that doesn't negate the fact he was awarded the nations highest honor,  and his action taken was retreating.   The motivation in the award was not to honor MacAurthur but to offset the propaganda value to the enemy for that action, ordered by the president.

Comment: @JMS Probably the most brilliant actions in the whole WWII were two retreats: Dunkirk, and specially Von Mannstein's miraculous escaping from Kursk.

Comment: @Rekesoft,   fair point, but in both cases the armies escaped / retreated not just the commander.   But your point is a fair one.

Comment: General Rommel was always dangerous while retreating too.  He knocked the stuffings out of an inexperienced US force in the first US meeting with the Germans at Kassering pass where technically Rommmel was retreating from the Brits.

Comment: @TheHonRose - Not just possible, but frankly more likely. If things are going swimmingly, there'd be no call for extreme heroics. (And I'd think you could easily have an opinion on this, as that particular medal is essentially the US equivalent to the Victoria Cross)

Comment: @T.E.D. Absolutely! *Apropos*, Rekescroft piqued my interest in Dunkirk. I know we Brits have rewritten a catastrophic retreat into the sea as a Great British Victory ;) (the French might disagree!), but I was surprised to find, AFAIK, only ONE VC was awarded, and that involved the rearguard action, not the actual evacuation, which, was, to be fair , a military/air and naval masterpiece.

Comment: @TheHonRose - I always preferred to view it as an Open Source evacuation. It could not fail, because there were simply too many participants to sink.

Comment: @T.E.D Hmm.. I might take issue with you there - no chauvinistic pride involved, of course ;) - but we've strayed a long way from the US Medal of Honor. Maybe subject for another question at some point.

Comment: @JMS Just off the top of my head, I imagine US forces were totally unprepared /untrained for desert warfare?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you take into account "fighting retreats." Perhaps the most famous ones come from the Korean War, one of America's less successful wars.

The battle of [Chosin Reservoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Chosin_Reservoir) in Korea was widely considered a retreat by the U.S. 1st Marine Division and 7th Infantry Division. This was even though the Marine Commander, General Oliver P. Smith put a brave face on it by saying something like, "Gentlemen, we are not retreating. We are attacking in a new direction."

Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Korean_War_Medal_of_Honor_recipients) of Congressional Medal of Honor Recipients that include at least three officers of that retreat, Lt. Col. Don Faith (of the 7th infantry), and Captain William Barber and Sgt. Robert Kennemore (1st Marine).

Also, [Major General William Dean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Chosin_Reservoir) commanding officer of the 24th Division during the early days, whose "fighting retreat" (which he personally led, wielding a bazooka and destroying an enemy tank), bought enough time for the rest of the U.N. forces to arrive.